# Software Center won't run in Loki

Tags: updates

Brand new install of Loki. When Software Center is clicked, the icon shows up on the dock for about 10 seconds and then goes away. nothing else happens. I reinstalled the SC but no change. I noticed during the reinstall many messages that packages could not be found. How to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean App Center? Or are you actually referring to the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the Lubuntu software Center and it works great, so I have removed thew Ubuntu SC. Don't know what's up with it.